# Find the indices of an array if it was sorted

Tags: sorting

Let's say I have an array {4,2,9,6}. I want to sort this array in ascending order. But instead
of the sorted array, I want the output to be the indices 
as if it was sorted. For example, in this case the sorted
array would be {2,4,6,9} and the desired output would be
{1,0,3,2}. I tried the following, but does not work. Any
suggestion please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;


void quickSort(int arr[], int index[], int left, int right) {
    int i = left, j = right;
    int tmp;
    int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

    /* partition */
    while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot)
            i++;
        while (arr[j] > pivot)
            j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            index[j] = index[i];
            arr[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    };

    /* recursion */
    if (left < j)
        quickSort(arr,index, left, j);
    if (i < right)
        quickSort(arr,index, i, right);
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int const N = 5;
    int arr[N], index[N];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        arr[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
        index[i] = i;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    int left = 0; int right = N-1;
    quickSort(arr,index, left, right);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        cout << index[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Can't you create tuples with <Value, OriginalIndex>, sort on the first and simply output the second

Comment: power of pointers would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with your problem and was able to do it with insertion sort. Here is my code (Java):

```
public static void insertionSortWithIndex(int[] a){
int x = 1;
// List<Integer> indexArray = new ArrayList<>();
int[] indexArray = new int[a.length];
int[] unsortedArray = new int[a.length];
for (int d = 0; d < a.length; d++) {
  unsortedArray[d] = a[d];
}

/* Your regular insertion sort algorithm */
while (x < a.length) {
  int c = x;
  while (c > 0 && a[c] < a[c-1]){
    swap(a, c, c-1);
    c--;
  }
  x++;


}
// System.out.println("Unsorted Array: " + Arrays.toString(unsortedArray));

 for (int unsorted = 0; unsorted < unsortedArray.length; unsorted++) {
    for (int sorted = 0; sorted < a.length; sorted++) {
      /* Main Index Ordering Logic: 
         if unsortedArray at unsorted index (unsortedArray[unsorted]) equals to sortedArray at sorted index, 
         then append unsorted index to will-be printed array */

        if (unsortedArray[unsorted] == a[sorted]) {
           indexArray[sorted] = unsorted; // append index of this number before sorting to indexArray at number's sorted position

      }

    }

  }

  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indexArray));

}


/* Swap Method */
public static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
  int temp = a[i];
  a[i] = a[j];
  a[j] = temp;


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] a {3, 4, 6, 5};

   insertionSortWithIndex(z);

   // output: {0, 1, 3, 2}
```

}

Essentially, what I did was add some extra logic onto the insertion sort algorithm so that it would return the correct array of indices based on the array of sorted numbers.

Note: this add-on may work with every sorting algorithm; however, I have not tested it out yet. In addition, this modified insertion sort algorithm only works with arrays where there are no repeated elements (as of Nov. 12, 2018). I will be testing, implementing these improvements, and updating the question soon.